# Silverstripe custom display rules—how to use the value of a select?

Tags: silverstripe

[image]

I'm trying to have a select field, and when I select an option, I want a second select box to appear.

The problem is that select fields don't have a value like text fields do. So, any comparison SS provides will fail—always thinking the select field is `''`.

Is there any way to compare the value of a select field?

Answer (score 2):

Use [display-logic](http://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic)

Disclaimer: I'm the author

Answer (score 0):

Use DependentDropdownFields, I found it easier for dropdowns than Display Logic for this case. (Sorry UncleCheese)